# usbip not working with OpenWRT

Tags: linux, embedded, usb, mips, openwrt

I am using MT7688 module with openWRT OS, version 15.05. I did install usbip into the device with:

```
#opkg install http://downloads.lede-project.org/releases/17.01.1/targets/ramips/mt7688/packages/kmod-usbip-client_4.4.61-1_mipsel_24kc.ipk
#opkg install http://downloads.lede-project.org/releases/17.01.1/targets/ramips/mt7688/packages/kmod-usbip-server_4.4.61-1_mipsel_24kc.ipk
#opkg install http://downloads.lede-project.org/releases/17.01.1/targets/ramips/mt7688/packages/kmod-usbip_4.4.61-1_mipsel_24kc.ipk
```

Failure scenario:

```
root@mylinkit:/# usbip
-ash: usbip: not found
```

So, looks like something broken at user space. Do any one know the solution for it?

Below are the logs which shows kernel module is installed:

```
root@mylinkit:/# lsmod|grep usbip
usbip_core              4768  2 vhci_hcd
usbip_host             11256  0 

root@mylinkit:/# find -name *usbip*
./etc/modules.d/usbip-server
./etc/modules.d/usbip
./etc/modules.d/usbip-client
./lib/modules/3.18.23/usbip-core.ko
./lib/modules/3.18.23/usbip-host.ko
./overlay/upper/etc/modules.d/usbip-server
./overlay/upper/etc/modules.d/usbip
./overlay/upper/etc/modules.d/usbip-client
./overlay/upper/lib/modules/3.18.23/usbip-core.ko
./overlay/upper/lib/modules/3.18.23/usbip-host.ko
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-server.postinst-pkg
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip.control
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-server.prerm
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-client.postinst
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip.list
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-client.prerm
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-server.list
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-server.postinst
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-client.control
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip.postinst
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip.prerm
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-server.control
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip.postinst-pkg
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-client.postinst-pkg
./overlay/upper/usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-client.list
./sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbip-host
./sys/devices/platform/vhci_hcd/usbip_debug
./sys/module/usbip_core
./sys/module/usbip_core/parameters/usbip_debug_flag
./sys/module/usbip_core/holders/usbip_host
./sys/module/usbcore/holders/usbip_host
./sys/module/usbip_host
./sys/module/usbip_host/drivers/usb:usbip-host
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-server.postinst-pkg
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip.control
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-server.prerm
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-client.postinst
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip.list
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-client.prerm
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-server.list
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-server.postinst
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-client.control
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip.postinst
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip.prerm
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-server.control
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip.postinst-pkg
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-client.postinst-pkg
./usr/lib/opkg/info/kmod-usbip-client.list
```

Comment: are you sure your $PATH variable has the path to the the usbip included? Did you try (from cmd-line) `/full/path/to/usbip` ? If you get the same error message **then** you know for certain that you have an install problem, but not yet. Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: share output of "which usbip"

Comment: I tried with 'which usbip' but command is not found in the system. There is no user space binary it seems. The one it /etc/modules.d/usbip doesn't look like the right candidate as usually it should be located in bin or sbin.

Comment: yes, but have to tried executing it. Check with file /etc/modules.d/usbip . also check and verify kernel version of your router(uname -r)

Answer (score 1):

I spend much time to figure out the solution. And in the end, doubt was correct. The installer `ipk` from release branch, as mentioned in query post, does not have user space binaries.

Solution: To get rid of it, I took complete source from official openwrt

```
 - `git clone https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt`
 - `make menuconfig`
 -  *Enabling from menuconfig*
 - `networking->usbip` `networking->usbip-client` and `networking->usbip-server`
```

And after compiling I got two binaries in sbin

```
/usr/sbin/usbip
/usr/sbin/usbipd
```

Which was needed and I was looking for. It works perfectly now.